# How to get DispatcherServeletInitializer functionality in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We are looking to migrate our project to Spring Boot. However it is unclear how to replicate the   functionality of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` in Spring Boot?

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
{
    return new Class<?>[]{AppConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
{
    return new Class<?>[]{WebappConfig.class};
}
@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings()
{
    return new String[]{"/"};
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters()
{
    DelegatingFilterProxy shiroFilter = new DelegatingFilterProxy("shiroFilter");
    shiroFilter.setTargetFilterLifecycle(true);

    CompositeFilter compositeFilter = new CompositeFilter();
    compositeFilter.setFilters(ImmutableList.of(new CorsFilter(),shiroFilter));

    return new Filter[]{compositeFilter};
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

The `AppConfig` and `WebappConfig` parent/child relationship can be handled by `SpringApplicationBuilder`, although you might also consider a flat hierarchy.

Assuming that you are going the whole hog, and running an embedded servlet container you can register `Filters` and `Servlets` directly as beans.

You can also use `ServletRegistrationBean` and `FilterRegistrationBean` if you need to set things such as `setAsyncSupported`. The final option is to add a bean that implements `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializer` then do the registration yourself.

Something like this might get you a bit further:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            new DispatcherServlet(), "/");
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public Filter compositeFilter() {
    CompositeFilter compositeFilter = new CompositeFilter();
    compositeFilter.setFilters(ImmutableList.of(new CorsFilter(), shiroFilter));
    return compositeFilter
}
```

Also, take a look at this section in the reference manual http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container

Comment: I am deploying as war. Not embedded container. Will the above work in that case too?

Comment: It should do if you use a `SpringBootServletInitializer`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is nothing special like just mark your `AppInitializer` with Boot annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
...
}
```

I haven't tried it, but just combined the documentation:

> Normally all the code from an existing WebApplicationInitializer can be moved into a SpringBootServletInitializer. If your existing application has more than one ApplicationContext (e.g. if it uses AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer) then you might be able to squash all your context sources into a single SpringApplication.

And `SpringBootServletInitializer` JavaDocs:

> If your application is more complicated consider using one of the
>   other WebApplicationInitializers.

Comment: Artem: the main problem with using the stock initializers is that you won't get the `SpringApplication` features. You can also use the `SpringApplicationBuilder` parent and child methods in `SpringBootServletInitializer` or in a custom initializer to create a hierarchy if that's what you need.