# how to Migrate AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hi I am new to spring boot currently I am trying to migrate my maven based web application to spring boot.
I was able to migrate all other configuration file except the below mentioned class:- ApplicationInitializer

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { Application.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter()};
        return singleton;
    }

}
```

I found one reference link similar to this [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869901/how-to-get-dispatcherserveletinitializer-functionality-in-spring-boot) which does the same work but I am not sure how to do this for my case.
Can anyone help me to figure it out that how to register my filter with dispatcher servlet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To register your filter with a dispatcher using SpringBootServletInitializer (that's what you refered to) you need to add FilterRegistrationBean. It may look like that:

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder application )
    {
        return application.sources( Application.class );
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean( ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean )
    {
        return new FilterRegistrationBean( new CORSFilter(), servletRegistrationBean );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }
}
```

Be aware that above code **replaces** your `ApplicationInitializer`.