# Same .war file with no .xml configuration Spring MVC app with Tomcat9. Running fine at localhost:8080, I got 404 error in Remote server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, web-deployment, tomcat9

I have trouble to deploy my web app into a remote server. 
It works completely fine when it's running on my machine - localhost:8080. (running fine at both cases at local machine where Tomcat started manually using .war file in **webapps** folder and, Eclipse - "run on server")

But I get 404 error when I try to connect after copying .war file into **/webapps/** folder in remote server. 
( I examed another sample.war file in the remote server, and it works fine. but not my .war file.)

I made .war file using command

```
$ mvn package
```

There is no web.xml file. and every configuration was made by java annotation. 
I Used Tomcat9. 
Also, I installed MySQL into Remote server. and managed everything in DB.

[image: folder structure]

ExceptionHandlers.java

```
package com.rainbowtape.boards.config;


@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlers {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handle(Exception ex) {

        return "404";
    }
}
```

MyServletInitializer.java

```
package com.rainbowtape.boards.config;


public class MyServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { PersistenceConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class, };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        boolean done = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true"); // -> true
        if(!done) throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] {
            new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()
        };
    }

}
```

NoHandlerFoundControllerAdvice.java

```
package com.rainbowtape.boards.config;

@ControllerAdvice
public class NoHandlerFoundControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handle(Exception ex) {
        return "redirect:/404";
    }

}
```

PersistenceConfig.java

```
package com.rainbowtape.boards.config;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.rainbowtape.boards"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.rainbowtape.boards.dao"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-mysql.properties"})
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.pass"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;     
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.rainbowtape.boards.entity");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
package com.rainbowtape.boards.config;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rainbowtape.boards")
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:///Users/rainbowtape/liffey-app/images/").setCachePeriod(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        springTemplateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"); 
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);

        mailSender.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("gmail.username"));
        mailSender.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("gmail.password"));

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        resolver.setResolveLazily(false);
        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.rainbowtape.boards.config;


@PropertySource({"classpath:maildata.properties"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true) 
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired 
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 

        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {

        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        http.addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
        http
        .csrf().disable() // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716632/spring-boot-request-method-post-not-supported
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/registerForm").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/forgotPassword/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/school/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/school/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/","/403","/register","/login","/loginError","/dbError","/404","/error","/validateLogin","/consulting","/test").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/validateLogin").permitAll()
        .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/")                                                     
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)                                                                                                 
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    private AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {

        return (request, response, exception) -> {
            if(exception.getMessage().contains("JDBC")) {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/dbError");
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/loginError");
            }
        };
    }

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {

        return (request, response, authentication) -> {
            if(authentication.getAuthorities().size() == 0) {
                log.info("User has no role.");
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/403");
            } else if(isAdmin(authentication)) {
                log.info("Admin");
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/admin/");
            } else {
                log.info("UserPage Redirecting");
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/user/");
            }
        };
    }

    private boolean isAdmin(Authentication auth) {

        System.err.println("isadmin?? - " + auth.getAuthorities().toString());

        boolean isAdmin = false;
        Iterator<? extends GrantedAuthority> i = auth.getAuthorities().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            if(i.next().toString().contains("ADMIN")) {
                isAdmin = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isAdmin;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rainbowtape</groupId>
    <artifactId>boards</artifactId>
    <name>spring-mvc-hibernate-boards</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.3.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- url parsing :: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter.twittertext/twitter-text -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter.twittertext</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter-text</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- file upload :: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mail :: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mail :: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dealing with html :: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jackson json bind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring data jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- thymeleap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>liffeyapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/liffeyapp
```

Can't fugure out, what was wrong... Would anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I am adding my remote server's catalina.out - log.

```
23-Feb-2019 00:24:33.066 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/liffeyapp]
23-Feb-2019 00:24:43.174 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/liffeyapp.war]
23-Feb-2019 00:24:43.194 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/liffeyapp]
 java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1527)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1428)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1435)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1266)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1229)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:825)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource$FinalizableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:852)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:175)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Conte

.
.
.
ContextLoader ----> ERROR: 2019-02-23 00:25:19,261 ----> Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.rainbowtape.boards.config.PersistenceConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4641)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
.
.
.
```

**EDIT 2**
Jave runtime verison was same.

Local

```
~:  java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Remote Server

```
root@vps*******:~# java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22871663/9923027[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22871663/9923027) ^^^ there's a better way to initialize your servlet beans

Answer (score 1):

I don't  know what was wrong. but what I did was..

I clean the project and delete everything in .m2/.repository

and.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
</dependency>
```

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you are compiling using Java 8 but running in Java 11?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

jaxb was deprecated from Java 9 and then removed in Java 11 (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320). Maybe the Java runtime version is the difference between your local and remote server.

Comment: No. Java runtime version was the same. I added it to the original post.